# Nested comments in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I try to do nested comments for posts, but I get this error: "column news_comment.parent_id does not exists". How can I solve this problem or any other realizations?

### serializers.py

```
        class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
              replys = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

              def get_replys(self, obj):
                    queryset = Comment.objects.filter(parent_id=obj.id)
                    serializer = CommentSerializer(queryset, many=True)
                    return serializer.data

              class Meta:
                model = Comment
                fields = '__all__'
```

```
        class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
                comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

                def get_comments(self, obj):
                    queryset = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=obj.id, parent_id=None)
                    serializer = CommentSerializer(queryset, many=True)
                    return serializer.data

                class Meta:
                    model = Post
                    fields = '__all__'
```

### models.py

```
        class Comment(models.Model):
            post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
            parent = models.ForeignKey(
              'self',
              default=None,
              blank=True,
              null=True,
              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
              verbose_name='parent',
              related_name='replys'
            )
            text = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
            date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
            username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Please ask the question in *English* or on [ru.SO].

Comment: Did you properly migrate your database? It looks like the database is not in sync with your model.

Comment: I migrated it with "makemigrations" and then "migrate" several times, but the error always appears

Comment: I think something wrong in the comment's model with parent field or in the CommentSerializer